# Android internal storage - what are the limits?

Tags: android, size, storage, limit, internal

1) Our Android app will store data in a built-in SQLite DB.

I see the DB can throw android.database.sqlite.SQLiteFullException, but there's no exact info in API what is the limit.

Could anyone tell what are the size limits for a DB in order not to get into the SQLiteFullException?

I assume DB will store data in device's internal storage (versus SDCard). Am I right? 
Given SQLite DB is just a file, probably the DB size is limited with free internal storage space. Again - Am I right? If yes, then what is the internal storage size on Android? How to detect it? Does it vary on a device model basis or OS version basis?

---

2) We'll also need to save app settings. I think SharedPreferences will fit nicely. However the question is - are SharedPreferences saved to the internal storage too? If yes, then is it the same storage where the DB stores its file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So any way to find the limit or size of SQLite DB. Or any way to find the database current writable status ? Or handling the exception is the only way?

Comment: We are doing it via handling exceptions (not even tried other ways).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I assume DB will store data in
>   device's internal storage (versus
>   SDCard). Am I right?

By default, yes.

> Given SQLite DB is just a file,
>   probably the DB size is limited with
>   free internal storage space. Again -
>   Am I right?

That would be my guess.

> Does it vary on a device model basis
>   or OS version basis?

On a device model basis.

> are SharedPreferences saved to the
>   internal storage too?

Yes.

> If yes, then is it the same storage
>   where the DB stores its file?

Yes.

Comment: what is the limit to store files in internal memory? @CommonsWare

Comment: @Quicklearner: There is no limit, other than the available disk space. There are hints that a quota system might be imposed in the future, but AFAIK that is not happening yet.

Comment: is it a good option to save images about more than 500 mb in it ?

Comment: @Quicklearner: Ah, I see your concern. Back in Android 1.x/2.x, internal storage had limited space. On current devices, internal and external storage share the on-board storage (think of them as being two separate partitions on the same hard drive). So, in general, the decision of whether to use internal or external storage is made on whether the user needs independent access to the file (in which case, use external storage). File size is less of an issue.